# the solana program reverted with the following error -- this account may not be used to pay transction fees l

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, rust, transactions

[image]

tudo que eu vou fazer na solana acontece isso e eu tenho muita taxa me ajudem

Comment: Can you please translate your query in English? Also the error seems to be because you don't have enough SOL.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site is not meant for wallet support

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that happens when the account is assigned to another program. That happens a lot lately.

Maybe this video of mine can help to recover some funds:
https://youtu.be/iX1mFUXbeFU